# Looking for a messaging service with api that lets me fan out messages to multiple users at once

Tags: android, web-apps, api, chat, message-broker

I want to offer a service to users so that I can disseminate messages which will be "fanned out" (sent to multiple users at the same time.

Ideally the features would include:

- offers an api to integrate in my development environment
- offers a web application to use within a browser
- offers mobile apps for Android, ios great but not a must
- need to be able to fan out messages to multiple users at the same time, one way traffic from my end to the users is sufficient
- users should not know about each other, hence a group chat is not desirable.
- the message content is text based but images would be of additional value to potentially disseminate charts in the future
- it should be easy for me to add new users to my messaging service.
- as there could me dozens of hundreds of messages per day email is not a viable alternative.

The purpose of this service is to disseminate messages to potential future clients.

Initially I prefer an open source or free service as this is a startup and is not run on a commercial basis yet.

Comment: You can't use email.... why?

Comment: Indeed email fits all your criteria perfectly – and your users even already have a fitting client in use :)

Comment: No email, as it would clutter peoples' inboxes as he frequency of messages would be potentially hundreds per day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telegram has a [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots) that does exactly what you seek.

They have [samples for all the possible programming languages](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples), so it's totally not a problem.

Going through your requirements:

- offers an api to integrate in my development environment

  **YES**.
- offers a web application to use within a browser

  **YES**.
- it should be easy for me to add new users to my messaging service.

  **Send links for joining to bots only to whom you want.**.
- the message content is text based but images would be of additional value to potentially disseminate charts in the future

  **YES, bots support images**.
- users should not know about each other, hence a group chat is not desirable.

  **The bot is NOT a chat, it is purely 1-to-1 experience. Bot sends commands, announcements, news and does not accept replies.**
- need to be able to fan out messages to multiple users at the same time, one way traffic from my end to the users is sufficient

  **Possible.**
- offers mobile apps for Android, ios great but not a must

  **YES.**

Answer (score 1):

[Matrix](http://matrix.org/) works pretty well for this.

- Can be run decentralised with other matrix "homeservers". Its a protocol - and synapse is the "best" supported server at the moment.
- is basically based off bog standard HTTP, and has a bunch of libraries for talking with it. [The API is usable over curl](http://matrix.org/docs/guides/client-server.html) and there's a good set of libraries
- [Riot](https://matrix.org/docs/projects/client/riot.html) is the preferred webclient
- Riot also has android and IOS ports
- Does private messenging.
- does images
- Synapse, the current official matrix server needs you to run a command to add users. I'd guess you might be able to reverse engineer and write something to bulk add users though.

Comment: Thank you but that sounds actually incredibly complex given the simple requirements. I had in mind something similar to hipchat or symphony

Comment: Its probably simpler, other than the need to host it yourself. Took me maybe 20 minutes to get up, including using letsencrypt certs.

Comment: Sure if you know the protocol, set up a self hosted server, use again a web client you know of. What does "preferred" webclient actually mean? I would like to consider alternatives that work as straight forward as Atlassian's hipchat without having to "hack" together a dozen different components in different languages.

Comment: But I take your effort seriously and will take a more thorough look at it. Thanks for your suggestion